# Cofactor matrix and trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix.
Is there any relation between $\operatorname{cofactor}(A)$ matrix and $\operatorname{trace}(A)$?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What let you think that there could be any relation? Or why do you want to know that?

Comment: For the sake of future posts, showing some effort to research the Question before posting will help in several ways.  It will give more structure to your problem formulation, and it will help Readers to understand your concern in a more precise way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two $n \times n$ matrices $A,B$, each with three equal rows.

Then 
$$\operatorname{cofactor}(A)=\operatorname{cofactor}(A)=0_n$$

But, as long as $n >3$ you can make $\operatorname{trace}(A), \operatorname{trace}(B)$ anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer to your question: Let $A$ be a positive definite symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Then by using the definition of determinant and trace according to eigenvalues, you can easily verify that $$det(A) \leq \frac{tr(A)}{n}.$$ Note that the equality holds, if $A$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix.

In general, we know that $adj(A)=(cof(A))^T$ and $A^{-1}= \frac{adj(A)}{det(A)}$.

Putting an order on $n \times n$ matrices induced by $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, one can obtain a probably useless, totally mechanic relation, which I do not continue anymore.

At least, if $A=cI$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $$A^{-1}= \frac{n.(cof(A))^T}{tr(A)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. There are some special cases however.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. $$det(A)=\sum A_{1i}A_{2j}A_{3j}... (-1)^\pi$$ for n terms where $det(A)$ is the determinant of $A$ and $\pi$ is whether the sequence of $i,j,k,...$ is an even or odd permutation of the $n$ terms. $\pi$ is $1$ for an even permutation, $-1$ for an odd permutation.

No require that $i=a$. Then $$det(A)=\sum_{i=a}^nA_{1i}(\sum A_{2j}A_{3k}...(-1)^\pi)$$

The term in parentheses is the cofactor of $A_{1i}$.

$Trace(A)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii}$.

A matrix with only diagonal elements has a determinant equal to the product of those elements. The Trace is the sum of those elements. For any set of $n$ integers such that their sum is equal to their product, you can construct a matrix which has a determinant equal to the trace, and the above relationship between determinants and cofactors will yield a relationship between cofactors and the trace in this specific case.